# Motion Events not appearing on Logcat

Tags: java, android-studio, action, touch-event

I am trying to detect click down event on the card class. The code for the update method of the card class is provided below. Whenever I click on the card no message is showing up. I have provided the full code for the card class below. My problem is to Add functionality to the Card class so it can detect a touch down event occurring on the card.

```
 public class Card extends Sprite {

    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Properties:
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Define the default card width and height
    private static final int DEFAULT_CARD_WIDTH = 90;
    private static final int DEFAULT_CARD_HEIGHT = 130;

    // Define the common card base
    private Bitmap mCardBase;

    // Define the card portrait image
    private Bitmap mCardPortrait;

    // Define the card digit images
    private Bitmap[] mCardDigits = new Bitmap[10];

    // Define the offset locations and scaling for the card portrait
    // card attack and card health values - all measured relative
    // to the centre of the object as a percentage of object size

    private Vector2 mAttackOffset = new Vector2(-0.68f, -0.84f);
    private Vector2 mAttackScale = new Vector2(0.1f, 0.1f);

    private Vector2 mHealthOffset = new Vector2(0.72f, -0.84f);
    private Vector2 mHealthScale = new Vector2(0.1f, 0.1f);

    private Vector2 mPortraitOffset = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.2f);
    private Vector2 mPortraitScale = new Vector2(0.55f, 0.55f);

    // Define the health and attack values
    private int mAttack;
    private int mHealth;



    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Constructors
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * Create a new platform.
     *
     * @param x          Centre y location of the platform
     * @param y          Centre x location of the platform
     * @param gameScreen Gamescreen to which this platform belongs
     */
    public Card(float x, float y, GameScreen gameScreen) {
        super(x, y, DEFAULT_CARD_WIDTH, DEFAULT_CARD_HEIGHT, null, gameScreen);

        AssetManager assetManager = gameScreen.getGame().getAssetManager();

        // Store the common card base image
        mCardBase = assetManager.getBitmap("CardBackground");

        // Store the card portrait image
        mCardPortrait = assetManager.getBitmap("CardPortrait");

        // Store each of the damage/health digits
        for(int digit = 0; digit <= 9; digit++)
            mCardDigits[digit] = assetManager.getBitmap(String.valueOf(digit));

        // Set default attack and health values
        mAttack = 1;
        mHealth = 2;
    }

    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Methods
    // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /**
     * Update the input demo
     *
     * @param motionEvent MotionEvent information
     */

    public void update(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

       float touchX = motionEvent.getX();
       float touchY = motionEvent.getY();
       int action = motionEvent.getAction();

       if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
           Log.i("card","is tapped");
       }
    }

    /**
     * Get the button touch location, converting from screen space to layer
     * space if needed. The touch location is stored within the specified
     * touchLocation vector.
     *
     * @param touchLocation  Touch location instance to be updated by this method.
     * @param x              Touch x screen location
     * @param y              Touch y screen location
     * @param layerViewport  Layer viewport
     * @param screenViewport Screen viewport
     */



      /**
     * Draw the game platform
     *
     * @param elapsedTime    Elapsed time information
     * @param graphics2D     Graphics instance
     * @param layerViewport  Game layer viewport
     * @param screenViewport Screen viewport
     */


        @Override
    public void draw(ElapsedTime elapsedTime, IGraphics2D graphics2D,
                     LayerViewport layerViewport, ScreenViewport screenViewport) {

        // Draw the portrait
        drawBitmap(mCardPortrait, mPortraitOffset, mPortraitScale,
                graphics2D, layerViewport, screenViewport);

        // Draw the card base background
        mBitmap = mCardBase;
        super.draw(elapsedTime, graphics2D, layerViewport, screenViewport);

        // Draw the attack value
        drawBitmap(mCardDigits[mAttack], mAttackOffset, mAttackScale,
                graphics2D, layerViewport, screenViewport);

        // Draw the attack value
        drawBitmap(mCardDigits[mHealth], mHealthOffset, mHealthScale,
                graphics2D, layerViewport, screenViewport);
    }



        private BoundingBox bound = new BoundingBox();

    /**
     * Method to draw out a specified bitmap using a specific offset (relative to the
     * position of this game object) and scaling (relative to the size of this game
     * object).
     *
     * @param bitmap Bitmap to draw
     * @param offset Offset vector
     * @param scale Scaling vector
     * @param graphics2D     Graphics instance
     * @param layerViewport  Game layer viewport
     * @param screenViewport Screen viewport
     */
    private void drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, Vector2 offset, Vector2 scale,
        IGraphics2D graphics2D, LayerViewport layerViewport, ScreenViewport screenViewport) {

//        // Calculate a game layer bound for the bitmap to be drawn
//        bound.set(position.x + mBound.halfWidth * offset.x,
//                position.y + mBound.halfHeight * offset.y,
//                mBound.halfWidth * scale.x,
//                mBound.halfHeight * scale.y);

        // Calculate the center position of the rotated offset point.
        double rotation = Math.toRadians(-this.orientation);
        float diffX = mBound.halfWidth * offset.x;
        float diffY = mBound.halfHeight * offset.y;
        float rotatedX = (float)(Math.cos(rotation) * diffX - Math.sin(rotation) * diffY + position.x);
        float rotatedY = (float)(Math.sin(rotation) * diffX + Math.cos(rotation) * diffY + position.y);

        // Calculate a game layer bound for the bitmap to be drawn
        bound.set(rotatedX, rotatedY,
                mBound.halfWidth * scale.x, mBound.halfHeight * scale.y);

        // Draw out the specified bitmap using the calculated bound.
        // The following code is based on the Sprite's draw method.
        if (GraphicsHelper.getSourceAndScreenRect(
                bound, bitmap, layerViewport, screenViewport, drawSourceRect, drawScreenRect)) {

            // Build an appropriate transformation matrix
            drawMatrix.reset();

            float scaleX = (float) drawScreenRect.width() / (float) drawSourceRect.width();
            float scaleY = (float) drawScreenRect.height() / (float) drawSourceRect.height();
            drawMatrix.postScale(scaleX, scaleY);

            drawMatrix.postRotate(orientation, scaleX * bitmap.getWidth()
                    / 2.0f, scaleY * bitmap.getHeight() / 2.0f);

            drawMatrix.postTranslate(drawScreenRect.left, drawScreenRect.top);

            // Draw the bitmap
            graphics2D.drawBitmap(bitmap, drawMatrix, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code snippet does not seems sufficient.
Please provide some more or sample code so that it will be clear what is scenario.
However, the most time view does not get touch-event when parent-view have consumed/intercepted the event. 
by default event is passed to child first until/unless it is not intercepted by parent.
Check for more detail here
https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup

Comment: I have edited the document now so it contains the full code for the card class. My problem is to add functionality to the Card class so it can detect a touch
drag event occurring on the card.